# Measure of closeness of a matrix to triangular form

Tags: matrices

Given a square $n\times n$ matrix $A$, I want to develop a measure of how close the matrix $A$ is to a triangular form.

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  What is your question, though?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Can you simply calculate the Frobenius norm of its strictly lower triangular part?